# find service using grep

Tags: services, grep

I am  trying to find specific service and I have question about this command:

```
service --status-all | grep worker
```

Why did `service --status-all | grep ...` not work?

Comment: In what way didn't it work, exactly? did you see something you didn't expect to see, or not see something that you did expect to see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There could be one of 2 issues here.

1. Either you have no process called worker - I didn't. Try to grep for `kill` or `dm` - you should see something for them.
2. You are seeing all of them. This is because it's giving it as lots of individual outputs, not just 1 thing.

   Each of those lines is printed separately, and it's as `stderr` not `stdout`. You have 2 options.

   1. Redirect to a file, like this:

      ```
      service --status-all > allout.txt 2>&1
      ```

      All the output will be saved in a file called `allout.txt`. You can then cat and grep that:

      ```
      cat allout.txt | grep worker
      ```

      That can be combined to one command:

      ```
      service --status-all > allout.txt 2>&1 && cat allout.txt | grep worker
      ```
   2. Redirect stderr to `/dev/null`, and grep `stdout`:

      ```
      service --status-all 2>&1 > /dev/null | grep worker
      ```

   Both of these give the same output:

   ```
   tim@Hairy14:~$ service --status-all > allout.txt 2>&1 && cat allout.txt | grep kill
    [ ? ]  killprocs
   ```

   and

   ```
   tim@Hairy14:~$ service --status-all 2>&1 > /dev/null | grep kill
    [ ? ]  killprocs
   ```

Answer (score 2):

You can easily use the hack double <kbd>Tab</kbd>

once you run :

```
sudo service wo
```

then double <kbd>Tab</kbd> this would automcplete or list all services startting with `wo`

---

you can still use grep if your terminal support colors

for example here is a test for my services:

```
 service --status-all | grep vnstat
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
service --status-all |& grep worker

service --status-all | grep vnstat
```

Comment: Please explain what the commands are doing!